# Extenal JS code

Tags: javascript, html

I started learning JS recently, and I have a problem I can not figure out... I tried a lot of solutions and nothing helped.

I have a very basic JS code:

```
<body>

<h1>My First JS Page</h1>

<p id="demo">My First Paragraph.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="My First JavaScript";
</script>

</body>
```

The code works when the script is below  but if I attach the same script as an external, and connects it to the HTML in the HEADER, the script just does not work ....

Comment: Can you post the code which is not working? i.e. the separate js file and the code by which you included that js in your page?

Comment: It generally helps if you show us code that doesn't work rather than code that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap external scripts in a

```
window.onload
```

example

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My first JS</title>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>My First JS Page</h1>
<p id="demo">My First Paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Filename test.js

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="My First JavaScript";
    //more code can go here if you want
}
```

Comment: can ypu pleas write the all code? include the HTML? 
im a beginner in JS and it's really hard for me to understand it without example...

Comment: @Nave Tseva two files 1 html and 1 js. In the html file you link to the js file.

Answer (score 1):

> the HTML in the HEADER

If you put the script in the `<head>` then it will appear before the `<p id="demo">`.

Since the script *immediately* tries to `getElementById('demo')`, that element doesn't exist. So it gets `undefined` instead of the element.

You need to either move the script to after the element (as it is in the code in the question), or wrap the code in a function and use that function as an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) (for an event that doesn't fire until the element exists, such as the load event).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the document or `<body>` part of a HTML page has not yet been loaded.

To overcome that issue, register an event handler to `onLoad` event of `<body>`, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function onDocumentReady() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="My First JavaScript";
}

window.onload = onDocumentReady;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My First JS Page</h1>

<p id="demo">My First Paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thenk you vey much! it works!!!
can i place the  onload="onDocumentReady()"
in other place? or that it must be located at BODY part? 
thank you again...

Comment: @NaveTseva - no, it must not. Another way is to assign `onDocumentReady` handler to `window.onload` which basically means the same thing. I updated my answer to show how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

This one is about order of operations. The script you have will run immediately once it is parsed by the browser, which means that if there is no rendered element with an id of "demo" nothing will happen. Simply place the `<script>` block above your `<p>` element and you'll notice this behavior ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NfdhD/)). In order to counter this, you need either to make sure all your scripts are at the end of the document (bad form) or that you're using some method to cause your scripts to run once the document is fully loaded (preferred). The two most common methods are either to use the `window.onload` event:

```
window.onload = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="My First JavaScript";
```

or to incorporate a JS library such as jQuery and use its built in method for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#demo").html("My First JavaScript");
}
```